# For which values is this function homogeneous?

Tags: homogeneous-equation

Given the function $u=z^\alpha_1z^\beta_2+\gamma z_3+\delta$,
for which non-negative values of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ is the function homogeneous?

I am only finding an answer where $\gamma = 0, \delta = 0$ with degree $\alpha+\beta$, but this means I lose the $z_3$ term, so it feels like I've got something wrong. Am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: Do you know what happens when you take $z_1^0$?